# Second floor leveling question

Tags: flooring, level, support

I have just recently purchased a business that has a large house on the property built in the 20's. Over time due to settling and likely some botched repairs the floor on the second floors slopes pretty badly.

Long story short, I have torn up the carpet and old hardwood which has left me with just the beams. The room slopes drastically from the outside in which is about 3 inches over a span of about 10 feet which is very noticeable. I can not shim up the low side because that will leave a 3 inch step into the room of which the ceilings and doorways are already incredibly low.

I know cutting beams should always be avoided but I was wondering if it would be alright to cut the beams on the tall side (2x8 beams) down roughly 2 inches and then sister new 2x6 beams to them to allow leveling as well as more support?

Answer (score 3):

it this case, it is not a home improvement project. Since it is a commercial building, you really need to have an engineer design a fix.  the liability is to great in rental or commercial property not to have it endorsed. Don't take a cheap fix, it will bite you. The safety of a lot of people depend on how you fix the problem.

Comment: I agree with you but in this case I actually plan to live there myself.

Comment: It's still serious engineering. Call a pro.